# Why are batch files considered to be a threat

Tags: windows, batch-file, virus

My friend is a beta tester for a Batch File *(compiled to .exe)* and his antivirus said that it is a virus, despite me not adding any code saying to control the computer or installing a backdoor. I used **MetalDefender** and out of the 42 scanners, 3 said it's a threat. Is it normal for PCs to do this? Why are batch files considered to be a threat?

Comment: Batch files are not considered a threat. But there are some threats coded in batch files and converted to `exe`. This leads to some false positives in some antivirus engines in the case of valid batch files using the same techniques.

Comment: So, some antiviruses automatically mark any batch files in .exe threats?

Comment: No, some antivirus see some of the `exe` wrapping programs as something suspicious as they have been seen in previous threats.

Comment: Your 'friend' is more than likely using a program which is disguising a batch file as something it isn't. Something which pretends to be something it isn't is obviously going to raise suspicions for some. _The usual reason for the virus warning isn't the actual disguise it's usually the added 'feature' of making that disguised program then work in stealth mode. My suggestion is therefore to ensure your disguised program is not made to run silently if you don't want it to raise suspicions_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Batch to exe "converter" doesn't actually convert anything at all. It only copies the Batch file contained in itself to a Temp folder and executes it.
This is highly suspicious behavior.